# How to change the first value in the tuple of a list?

Tags: python, numpy, replace, tuples

This is my matrix:

```
b = [[(1, 0.044), (2, 0.042)], [(4, 0.18), (6, 0.023)], [(4, 0.03), (5, 
0.023)]]
```

And I want to let it to be a

```
b = [[(6, 0.044), (7, 0.042)], [(9, 0.18), (11, 0.023)], [(9, 0.03), (10, 
0.023)]]
```

To add n for the first value in the tuple, and I tried:

```
for n in b:
    for ee,ww in n:
        ee == ee + 2903
```

It doesn't work.
How should I keep the change to the original matrix b?

Comment: Tuples are immutable; at the least, you need to replace each tuple with a new one in each sublist.

Comment: I don't understand where the `2903` comes from, and `b` is three levels deep while your for loop is only two. Also you're using the comparison `==` rather than the assignment `=`.

Comment: If I gave you a function `update`, would it have to update `b` in place, so that `print(b); update(b); print(b)` would output two different values, or can it return a copy `new_b = update(b)`. In the second case, do you need to retain the original object? That is, after `new_b = update(b)`, would you require `id(new_b) == id(b)`? Would you require that `id(new_b[0]) == id(b[0])` as well? (Keeping the existing rows, and only replacing the tuples within each row?)

Comment: `ee== ..` is not an assignment.  And `ee=..` changes the variable but does not change `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Tuples are immutable. You can use a list comprehension instead:

```
res = [[(i+5, j) for i, j in tup] for tup in b]

[[(6, 0.044), (7, 0.042)], [(9, 0.18), (11, 0.023)], [(9, 0.03), (10, 0.023)]]
```

Comment: This builds an entirely new matrix, rather than updating the existing one. Depending on the use case, this may not be useful.

Comment: @chepner, Sure. I think there are fundamental flaws in understanding for OP, e.g. the use of the term "matrix". I think we need more clarity to be sure a list comprehension does *not* suffice. Of course, time complexity is the same either way, there's no *intrinsic* benefit to modifying the "existing matrix" if either would work.

Comment: I read the original question ("... keep the change to the original matrix b") as indicating that this might be, for example, inside a function that takes `b` as an argument and updates it in-place.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify tuples, they are immutable in Python. You can however replace the existing tuples with other tuples.

```
b = [[(1, 0.044), (2, 0.042)], [(4, 0.18), (6, 0.023)], [(4, 0.03), (5, 0.023)]]
for n in b:
    for i, (ee, ww) in enumerate(n):
        n[i] = (ee + 2903, ww)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[(2904, 0.044), (2905, 0.042)], [(2907, 0.18), (2909, 0.023)], [(2907, 0.03), (2908, 0.023)]]
```